# Can't Shutdown or Reboot from GUI after making new user

Tags: gui

As the title says I cannot shutdown or reboot from the GUI (when I say GUI I mean the one that loads after the `startx` command) after I am done. I can logout and reboot from command line but I cannot do it at once.

I have added another user, made him root and deleted `pi` user - if that matters - it appears the problem started after this change.

Can this be fixed?

I can post if you can tell me how or point me to where I should read so I can provide them.

Another problem I had after I created the new user was that the GUI taskbar was flashing and was unavailable for everything. After googling I fixed it by typing

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio <your_user>
```

P.S. I managed to reboot from SSH and from Ctrl+Alt+F2 but it still looks like I have a problem to fix. Please help.

Commands I used are:

```
>sudo adduser newuser 
>sudo visudo (to make him root) 
>sudo deluser -remove-home pi (to delete pi/remove pi user)
```

Note that I went through all this to harden my SSH because I want to use my raspberry pi over the net. Hence I will have to do it again after flashing and I'm afraid I will just reproduce the same problem.

Comment: How did you create the new user? Raspbian doesn't have a `root` login but there is a root user. It is probably going to be easier to just reflash your SD card and restart.

Comment: Commands I used are:
>sudo adduser newuser
>sudo visudo (to make him root)
>sudo deluser -remove-home pi (to delete pi/remove pi user)

Note that I went through all this to harden my SSH because I want to use my raspberry pi over the net. Hence I will have to do it again after flashing and I m afraid I will just reproduce the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear exactly what you did. `visudo` does not make a user `root`.

Did you login as `newuser` before deleting `pi`?

You need to make the user a member of many groups to actually do anything try:-

```
for GROUP in adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users netdev input spi i2c gpio; do sudo adduser newuser $GROUP; done
```

I fear you have broken your installation if you deleted `pi` before login as `newuser`.

While I have posted the above, I do not see that changing user will "harden my SSH". There are better ways to do that, such as setting public/private keys and disabling password login.

Comment: You are right I probably broke my installation because I didn't know one should add a new user to groups. After researching I figured it out and did the following:

>sudo adduser newuser 
>sudo visudo (to make him root) 
>sudo usermod -a -G adm,dialout,cdrom,sudo,audio,video,plugdev,games,users,netdev,input,indiecity newuser

Then I checked that everything worked ok and I deleted user pi. Stuff continued to work fine.

I know that private keys are safer for SSH hardening but I didn't want to dive into those waters yet.

Anyway, fixed now that I know about user groups.
Thank you for your help!