# Trying to kill all processes, but new processes keep spawning

Tags: linux, sudo, user, process

I'm trying to rename the default `pi` username after getting a new raspberry pi 4. I am completely new to Linux, so my knowledge of the matter is small. From what I've discovered, one way to rename `pi` is to create a new root user and run commands from `root`. I ran the following command to do this,

```
sudo passwd root
```

I then entered the password, logged out of `pi` and into `root`. In `root`, I ran the following to change from `pi` to `joffin` (my favorite made up name),

```
root@raspberrypi:~# killall --user pi
root@raspberrypi:~# usermod -l joffin pi
usermod: user pi is currently used by process 8630
```

then ran this to get details for y'all to see (I don't know what this means).

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ps -lp 8630
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000  8630     1  0  80   0 -  3679 do_epo ?        00:00:00 systemd
```

I tried again ...

```
root@raspberrypi:~# killall --user pi
root@raspberrypi:~# usermod -l joffin pi
usermod: user pi is currently used by process 8675
root@raspberrypi:~# ps -lp 8675
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000  8675     1  0  80   0 -  3679 do_epo ?        00:00:00 systemd
```

How can I keep these new processes from spawning so that I can rename my pi?

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself a lot of angst. There are a lot of similar posts, but no satisfactory solution.

As you have discovered the name pi is used in lots of places. It is coded into many scripts. It is not actually impossible to rename pi, but requires considerable Linux expertise.

What many of us do is create a new user and give this account all the privileges of the pi user. Even this requires some expertise but you can find tutorials.

The following will copy groups from user **pi**

```
sudo adduser username
#copy groups from user pi:-
    for GROUP in $(groups pi | sed 's/.*:\spi//'); do sudo adduser username $GROUP; done
```

You can then login to this account and prevent pi from logging in. It may be possible to then delete the pi account but there is little benefit.

Comment: I'll give this a try and get back with you

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36347/8697 which may help

Comment: I haven't done it yet, but would there be any bad consequences for deleting `pi`?

Comment: One consequence is that if you haven't correctly and successfully transferred all the permissions to a new account, you'll end up locked out.  It's really easier to just leave the pi account, maybe change its password for a while, and lock it out when you are very sure.

Comment: @user10489 Would `adduser joffin sudo` from root successfully transfer everything?

Comment: @GabeMorris DO NOT ask questions in Comments. Edit your question.